# free software supported both ligatures and color fonts

Tags: fonts, free, presentation-design, ligatures, quarkxpress

I would like to prepare educational materials for children. Exactly what I mean is charts with alphabet letters and pictures. Such boards could be printed or shown as a multimedia presentation. The ideal solution for Windows would seem to be Power Point or OO Impress. Unfortunately, they do not support color fonts and ligatures, which I care about the most. Is there any multimedia presentation software that supports both ligatures and color fonts? I can also make these charts in programs like QuarkXpress or Illustrator and then somehow solve the problem of efficient transfer of the charts to PowerPoint. My question is: does anyone know any free software I could use in my project? I mean the programs for:
 - raster and vector graphics
 - multimedia presentations
supported ligatures and color fonts.
I am not limited to Windows and offline solutions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! It's unclear to me exactly what you're asking for - *color fonts and ligatures* I believe Powerpoint does allow you to change the color of any text. as far as ligatures, do you mean English language text ligatures like these:
[example](https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/level-3/signs-and-symbols/ligatures-1)? Do you have an image you can share to help explain what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, I mean text ligatures like in your example. Here you find some information about color fonts:  https://www.colorfonts.wtf/. I want to make such charts as efficiently as possible: https://srv19859.microhost.com.pl/2019-10-30_20h38_34.jpg School font from this example requires ligatures and color font format COLR support. I am not limited to COLR. Formats can be converted in trans type: https://www.fontlab.com/font-converter/transtype/

Comment: I'm amazed [PowerPoint does not support OT ligatures](https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/264636-general/suggestions/38143594-support-opentype-features-in-powerpoint). However, if Word does, is it possible to import a Word doc into PowerPoint as the basis of the presentation?

Comment: I was amazed too, but Publisher supports, unfortunately without color fonts. I didn't try import Word doc to PP.